# Excel Sum Values of Matching rows through large range

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that is meant for inventory tracking / production purposes.

My basic layout is as follows:

Each production machine has 4 cells associated with it and the pattern repeats for all lines.

The cells are: A4. Product
               A5. Theoretical production value (automatic calculation)
               A6. Actual Production value (user input)
               A7. Subtotal (Sum of A6 if A4 matches on the previous day)

To further clarify, assume that A is for Monday, And A4-A7 are for Line 1's product / production for Monday. B is for Tuesday, B4-B7 would be for Line 1's product / production for Tuesday and so forth. Line 2 would be A8-A11.

Everything on that end works fine. I have another tab called Inventory that has the product number on Column A and the subtotal of that product on Column B.

So for sake of simplicity, let's assume that I want to know the total production for Product A4. Is there a way for me to sum up all of the values on the 6th row where there is a match between the value on the 4th row with the Product on Inventory A? I know how to use Vlookup, and this seems like something where I would have to use hlookup, but everything I've tried to so far has not worked. Each Product has a possibility of running on 3 lines, but if someone can help me do it for 1 line, I can adapt it for the rest.

```
=SUMIF(January2014!$A4:January2014!$ND4,A4, January2014!$A6:January2014!$ND6)
```

The formula above sort of does what I need it to, but for some reason it fails to sum up the latest entry. January 2014 is the tab where A4-A7 example would be and and this formula appear in Column B of the Product page.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? with xLOOKUPs? show us some code and we will be happy to help you.  Also, could you show us some sample of the data?

Comment: Hey PA, see my edit for what I've tried.

Comment: don't quite get it. could you please improve your example using the same rows and cols A4..A7? what does A27 contain? could you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Sure thing, sorry for the lack of clarification I had a hard time wording this question. A27 contains the 'Product' the thing that is supposed to match with anything on row 4.

Comment: I actually figured it out, though. I messed up my formula. I will answer it below. Thanks PA!

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMIF(January2014!$A4:January2014!$ND4,A4, January2014!$A6:January2014!$ND6)
```

The formula above will sum up all cells from A6 to ND6 if there is a match between A4 on the product spreadsheet and A4 to ND4 on the January2014 spreadsheet.